# Applying bootstrap has-error styling to a select2 element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2, styling

I've got a [`select2`](https://select2.github.io/) select menu.

Stripped version for example:

```html
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <select name="description_id" class="select2">
        <!-- <options> -->

</div>
```

Applying the `has-error` to the text-inputs will display a red border around the input. This does not work for a `select2` menu. What am I missing?

I'm using `bootstrap3` and the latest `select2`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The solution on the page you have posted, is for an older version of `select2`. For the latest version, use this CSS code here:

```
.has-error .select2-selection {
    border-color: rgb(185, 74, 72) !important;
}
```

Now with this code and using the `has-error` class, you can get the proper reddish error color:

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
 <select name="description_id" class="select2">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

[image: Select2 with has-error class]

jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/k9phxgnd/1/

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot, can award the bounty in 12 hours :-)

Answer (score 5):

With Bootstrap 3.3 and Select2 4.0.6 the error styling may be applied as follows:

css:

```
.has-error {border:1px solid rgb(185, 74, 72) !important;}
```

jquery/javascript:

```
$('#YourSelect2ControlID').next().find('.select2-selection').addClass('has-error');
```

For Select2 controls the object containing the border styling is not the `<select>` element, it is one of the nested `<span>` elements following the `<select>` element. That particular span contains the `.select2-selection` class.